# Error Enviar Archivo REACTJ

Tags: reactjs

Buen día comunidad.
Tengo el siguiente problema:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://[ip]:50115/ArchivoUsuario/Worklog/' from origin 'http://[i]'
> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't
> pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource.

La información de documento es correctamente vaciada a mi BD por medio de API.
En front arroja error.

Cualquier ayuda se agradece, Saludos!

Anexo código:

```
 const uploadFile = async ( excel: File) => {
    try {
        if ( excel != null ) {
            setLoading(true);
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append( "formFile", excel );
            formData.append( "fileName", excel?.name );
            var res = await axios.post( `http://${process.env.REACT_APP_APIGATEWAY}:50100/ArchivoUsuario/Worklog`, formData)
            .then((res) => {   
                setOpenSucces(true);                   
              })
            .catch((err) =>{
                setOpenFail(true);
            }) 
            setLoading( false )
        } 
    } catch (ex) {
        setLoading( false )
    }
};

//Constante para subir archivo
const handleChangeFile = async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.target.files != null) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if ( file instanceof File) {
            uploadFile( file );
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revisa tu backend, si tienes configurado un cors, puedes probar usando

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({*}));
```

Comment: Eso fue uno de los problemas. La solucion de esta pregunta fue permisos de acceder  a formfile en el back, almacenado en una carpeta